# Как вытащить элемент из ответа запроса используя for в python

Tags: python, list, rest, for

Я делаю запрос используя метод, который записан в функцию get_hashtag_post, который находится в классе FeedController, из данного запроса получаю ответ, где есть поле body, в котором находится параметр id со значением.

Ответ на request_hashtag выглядит так:

```
{
  "status": {
    "headers": {},
    "body": "None",
    "statusCode": "OK",
    "statusCodeValue": 200
  },
  "body": [
    {
      "id": 42667,
      "text": "#sokoban",
      "createdDateTime": "2022-11-02T08:54:31.288790Z",
      "inGameId": "None",
      "source": "TOP",
      "postsBlock": "USER",
      "author": {
```

Мне нужно вытащить это значение, используя цикл, для того что бы в следующем запросе поставить лайк на полученный id. Затем мне нужно будет вытащить несколько id, чтобы поставить лайки на них всех.

```
def test_list():
    request_hashtag = FeedController().get_hashtag_post(hashtag='sokoban', params=description_top_2)
expected_status = "OK"
    for expected_id in request_hashtag['body'][0]['id']:
        print(expected_id)
    request_id = ProfileUpdate().like_post(post_id=expected_id, json=post_like)
    with allure.step("Проверка что пост лайкнут, statusCode ОК и statusCodeValue 200"):
        assert a['body'][0]['id'] == 42667 and a['body']["meLiked"] is True and a['status']['statusCode'] == expected_status
```

Сейчас, если запускаю код то появляется ошибка:

```
def test_list():
        request_hashtag = FeedController().get_hashtag_post(hashtag='sokoban', params=description_top_2)    
        for expected_id in request_hashtag['body'][0]['id']:
            print(expected_id)

>       for expected_id in request_hashtag['body'][0]['id']:
E       TypeError: 'int' object is not iterable
```

Comment: может вы покажите, как выглядит request_hashtag или нам надо догадаться?

Comment: добавил json ответ в описание к вопросу

Comment: request_hashtag['body'][0]['id'] - это уже значение id, какой там цикл. цикл можно устроить по ['body'][ i ]['id'] `for x in request_hashtag['body']: expected_id = x['id'] `

Comment: да, но это кусок ответа, в полноценном ответе будет 5 штук id и мне нужно проверить, что на все эти id поставлен лайк через assert

Comment: мне нужно не быть привязанным к ['body][0]['id']
а сделать проверку по ['body']['id']

Comment: я написал в комментарии цикл. попробуйте страницу обновить

Comment: все, спасибо вам!